# Memory leak in iphone App when analyzed

Tags: iphone, ios5, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak signal like the one shown in [image]

how can i clear this, please help me .

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using ARC? Wouldn't just calling [newString autorelease]; before returning solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`(__bridge_transfer NSString *)`** instead of **`(__bridge NSString *)`**

With **ARC**, you can use **`__bridge_transfer`** to transfer memory management of the returned string to **ARC**

**Example:**

```
NSString *myString = [self encodeURL:@"hi*)"];
NSLog(@"%@",myString);

-(NSString *)encodeURL:(NSString *)string{

    NSString *newString = @"";        
    newString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("^%*)*&%$"),CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));              
    return newString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 NSString *newString = nil;
 CFStringRef stringRef = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(...);
 newString = (NSString *)stringRef;
 CFRelease(stringRef);

 if(newString)
      return newString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return [newString autorelease];
```

The `NSString` object  `newString` is got allocated in the function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.

so the object attaining the retain count of one at this moment. So when you are retuning the retained object you got memory leak signal. We can add the object `newString` to the autorelease pool so that the os will take care of the memory to release at the right time.

Hope this helps.